# (JAVA) Converting a coloured image to a black and white border sketch

Tags: java

Recently, I was given an exercise which requires me to read a data file and use it to generate a coloured-image as an output. Now, I was given another exercise which is to convert the coloured image to a black and white sketch.

The code below is what I've constructed to generate the coloured image

```
//Setting the size of the graphics window
    final int WINDOW_DIMENSION = 200;
    final int SIZE_FACTOR = 3;
    EasyGraphics generate = new EasyGraphics(WINDOW_DIMENSION*SIZE_FACTOR,WINDOW_DIMENSION*SIZE_FACTOR);

    //Constructing the arrays
    char[][] firstArray = new char[WINDOW_DIMENSION][WINDOW_DIMENSION];
    char[] secondArray = scan.toCharArray();

    //Using "for" loop to generate 2D array
    int line = WINDOW_DIMENSION;
    int column = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_DIMENSION*WINDOW_DIMENSION; i++) {
        column++;
        if (i%WINDOW_DIMENSION == 0) {
            line--;
            column = 0;
        }

        firstArray[column][line]=secondArray[i];
    }

    //Plotting the colours for respective range of numbers
    for (int a = 0; a < WINDOW_DIMENSION; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < WINDOW_DIMENSION; b++) {
            if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
                //Colour of background
                generate.setColor(66,167,243);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='4' || firstArray[a][b]=='5') {
                //Colour of leaves
                generate.setColor(0,255,77);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='6' || firstArray[a][b]=='7') {
                //Colour of ground
                generate.setColor(51,183,91);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='8' || firstArray[a][b]=='9') {
                //Colour of tree trunk
                generate.setColor(102,51,0);
                for (int da=0; da<3; da++) {
                    for (int db=0; db<3; db++) {
                      generate.plot(a*3+da,b*3+db);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

My friend attempted the exercise and almost perfected it. You can see his results by looking at the link given: http://prntscr.com/57yi87.

His image supposed to generate a picture which is mostly white but the colour boundaries of the original picture are in black. I tried using loops to do it but to no avail. Any solutions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in code you're loading an image and making it bigger (with color mapping in the process). But from your post it seems like you need to find contours and get black&white image. Where's the code for that? What have you tried? What loops are you talking about?

If you want to generate contour image, the simplest way I know is to use Prewitt operator or Sobel operator.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

P.S.
This would be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.